# Change SQL delimiter for SQL files in VS Code editor

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm working on some projects from different customers.

For one project devs used SQL delimiter as a semicolon (the default for the majority - if not all - SGBDs out there).

```
;
```

But for the other, devs used a backtick:

```
`
```

The problem is, for the later, during VS Code editing using default SQL editor, the syntax coloring becomes hard to read long SQL files, with many instructions. Even on git compare it mess up with colors. Every statement between 2 backticks are considered a comment.

Is there any other editor/plugin on which I can change the default SQL command delimiter to a backtick ? I can't change delimiter since they have a legacy SQL pre-processor/executor that depends on the backtick to work.

Example:
[image]